# How to insert object into collection if it doesn't exist using mongo-jackson-mapper?

Tags: mongodb, jackson, mongo-jackson-mapper

I can't find an API for this simple operation. What I need to do is insert a new document if it doesn't exist already, so I'm trying to use "upsert":

```
JacksonDBCollection<User, String> collection = 
    JacksonDBCollection.wrap(database.getCollection("users"), 
            User.class, String.class);
collection.ensureIndex("email");
collection.update(DBQuery.in("email", user.email),
    <what should I put here?>, true, false);
```

The object I need to insert is "user", but update() signature accepts only DBQuery instance.

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: did you see the code in this link: https://github.com/vznet/mongo-jackson-mapper/commit/7726bf2a4973c36dc4986333f81d6f4476775451

Comment: @AsyaKamsky this code only updates one of object fields. What I need is to insert a **new** document if it doesn't exist.

Comment: it updates that field or inserts the document with that field set if the document doesn't exist.  That's what the upsert flag does.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky, so I have to count all existing fields of the object into DBObject, or there some syntactic sugar for that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "to count" so can't really say, sorry.